# Passing file name with spaces to SPOOL command using SQL Plus gives SP2-0768 Illegral SPOOL command error

Tags: c#, sqlplus, oracle11gr2, spool

My sql file contains

```
`SPOOL &1;
//sql code to execute
SPOOL OFF;`
```

The sql file is executed using SQL Plus and SQL Plus is being called from C# code using Process.Start... Code snipped

```
`var m_StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
m_StartInfo.FileName = "SQLPLUS.EXE";
m_StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
m_StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
m_StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("{0}\"{1}\" \"{2}\"", connectionString, sqlfile, sqlLogFileName);
m_Process = Process.Start(m_StartInfo);
Other code.....`
```

It works fine and the sqlplus log is created fine at sqlLogFileName location. However if the sqlLogFileName has spaces in between (say like "C:\My Application\log.txt"), then the log file is not created, instead gives the error SP2-0768 Illegal SPOOL command on SQL Plus window

Any suggestion how to resolve this? I am using Oracle 11GR2

Comment: Everything I've found on the internet says you need to use ">" to specify output to your log file. So the format string for `m_StartInfo.Arguments` should be `"{0}\"{1}\" >\"{2}\""`. They make no mention of using the Spool command actively in the SQL script itself.

Comment: Using ">" didn't solve the problem. I removed spool &1 from sql file and pass the m_StratInfo.Arguments as "{0}\"{1}\" >\"{2}\"" but it didn't crete the log file

Answer (score 2):

You just have to surround your file name with double quotes. 
Something like:

`spool "Test with spaces.txt"`

Or in your case with a parameter:

```
SPOOL "&1"
```

I think is best not to use spaces though, as @tvCa explained.

**Side Note:**

What StarPilot is refering to, I believe, is about the [redirect a command output to a file](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true), and that is why it didn't work when you tried to use it.
For example in command prompt you would write:

`dir > dir.txt`

And that saves the output of dir inside dir.txt.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle software is designed to be used with directories not having whitespaces (which is an accepted standard in Linux/Unix, even though technically you can do otherwise). On Windows, things are different, but the Oracle software has the same idea : it does not like whitespaces. So, the fix is clear : spool to a directory without whitespaces. This is advice, anybody is free to take or not.